# Web Scraping with Python BS

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrape some weather data off of Weather Underground.  I haven't had any difficulty getting the data of interest until I came to getting the day/date, hi/lo temps, and forecast (ie. "Partly Cloudy").  Each is in a div without a class.  The parent, of each, is a div with a class="obs-date" (see image below)

[WxUn HTML image][1]

Attempted code below with other options commented out.  Each returns an empty list.

```
def get_wx(city, state):
    city=city.lower()
    state=state.lower()
    
    # get current conditions; 'weather' in url
    current_dict = get_current(city, state)

    # get forecast; 'forecast' in url
    f_url = f'https://www.wunderground.com/forecast/us/{state}/{city}'
    f_response = req.get(f_url)
    f_soup = BeautifulSoup(f_response.text, 'html.parser')
    cast_dates = f_soup.find_all('div', class_="obs-date")
    # cast_dates = f_soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class":"obs-date"})
    # cast_dates = f_soup.select('div.obs-date')
    print(cast_dates)
    
get_wx("Portland", "ME")
```

Any help with what I'm missing is appreciated.

Comment: Please share a *minimal* example in text form of the html document you are working with.

Comment: [OpenWeatherMap](https://openweathermap.org/) offers weather as JSON data using its [API](https://openweathermap.org/api) and this is much simpler.

Comment: maybe get all `divs` and use indexes in Python to get expected `div` - `all_divs[0]`, `all_divs[1]`,

Comment: the problem can be: page uses `JavaScript` to add elements to HTML but `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript. It may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`.

Comment: you can always nested `find`/`find_all`. You can use `cast_dates[0].find_all(...)` to search only inside first `cast_dates` - and you can use `for`-loop to repeate it for all elements. `for item in  cast_dates: item.find_all(...)`

Comment: api is way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the whole block you're trying to parse is driven by javascript, that's why you're getting empty results using `beautifulsoup`

The *ADDITIONAL CONDITIONS* part could be parsed completely using `bs4` as well as everything below. Table at the end could be parsed using `pandas`.

To scrape javascript content, you can use `requests-html` or `selenium` libraries.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import json

session = HTMLSession()
url = "https://www.wunderground.com/weather/us/me/portland"
response = session.get(url)
response.html.render(sleep=1)

data = []

current_date = response.html.find('.timestamp strong', first = True).text
weather_conditions = response.html.find('.condition-icon p', first = True).text
gusts = response.html.find('.medium-uncentered span', first = True).text
current_temp = response.html.find('.current-temp .is-degree-visible', first = True).text

data.append({
    "Last update": current_date,
    "Current weather": weather_conditions,
    "Temperature": current_temp,
    "Gusts": gusts,
})

print(json.dumps(data, indent = 2, ensure_ascii = False))
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "Last update": "1:27 PM EDT on April 14, 2021",
    "Current weather": "Fair",
    "Temperature": "49 F",
    "Gusts": "13 mph"
  }
]
```